# base.html not extending fully on certain page with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

On one certain page of my flask project, the base.html is not properly extending.

On this page we can see that the footer is visible and javascript is in the source:
[image]
[image]

On this page the footer is not visible and javascript not in the source. The footer and the javascript should be visible but is not:
[[image]
[image]

Why is this happening? There are no error messages for either the javascript or python code. I have tried ChatGPT and it couldn't find anything. I also tried googling but that turned up no results either.
The header section is extended correctly but the footer and javascript on this specific page is not.
Below is the code for my base.html, a standard working page, and the broken page.

**Code**

*base.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - MUMC</title>
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<div class="base-header">
</div>
<br/>
<!--[if lte IE 11]>
  <h1>Please upgrade your browser. As many functions will not work without a modern browser.</h1>
<![endif]-->
<!-- some omitted html code is here -->
  <section class="content">
    <header>
      {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    </header>
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
      <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </section>
</div>
<footer class="base-footer">
  <h4>Copyright (c) Melbourne University Mountaineering Club 2023 - Designed by Tom Eccleston</h4>
  <button id="stylebutton">Make it look <div id="pretty" style="display: inline;">pretty</div><div id="ugly" style="display: none;">ugly</div></button>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
 // bunch of Javascript  

</script>
```

*Working page*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Links and Weather
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="weatherslider">
        <h2>Weather Slider</h2>
        <!-- some omitted html code is here -->
    </div>
    <div class="links">.
        <div class="shop">
            <h2>Where to get gear</h2>
            <a href="https://www.bogong.com.au/" target="_blank">Bogong - Hiking Equipment</a>
        </div>
        <div class="googleMaps">
            <h2>Where we are located</h2>
            
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*Not working html page*

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}
Gallery
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="gallery">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <table class="gallery">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/Approach.jpg')}}" width=170 height=130></td>
                    <td class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/Climb.jpg')}}" width=170 height=130></td>
                    <td class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/Heaven.jpg')}}" width=170 height=130></td>
                    <td class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/Highland.jpg')}}" width=170 height=130></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="video" style="margin: auto; margin-left: 7em;">
            <iframe src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/MUMC.mp4')}}" width=700 height=300>
        </div>
        <div id="enlarged_photo" style="margin: auto; padding: 10px; width: 50%; align-items: center; display: none;">
            <img id="fullscreen" src="" width=700 height=400 style="z-index: 4; position: block;">
            <br/>
            <p style="z-index: 4;" id="info">You can leave this photo at anything by pressing 'esc'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```